# Importing/including other libraries in a C project

Tags: c, makefile, bson

You'll have to forgive me as I'm a bit new at C development. I'm working through the awesome guide found at [c.learncodethehardway.com](http://c.learncodethehardway.com), so bear with me.

I'm trying to write a simple program which uses [libbson](https://github.com/mongodb/libbson) to read and write a BSON tree to and from disk. In the past, I've usually just done `apt-get install openssl-dev` or the like to install headers on my system, but libbson is kind of new and doesn't exist in a deb form yet. Plus, I'd like my project to ship with it statically compiled-in for now until it becomes more widely available.

I know fairly basic things like the general format of a Makefile and how to write fairly simple stuff in C. How and where would I include the source code of libbson into my project to by statically compiled into my executables?

(Using `gcc` and would like to encapsulate compilation into a Makefile)

Comment: You have the full source code for libbson available? If so, you can just compile those files like the rest of your project files – include the headers in the source files that use them, and link to the .cpp files when compiling.

Comment: Command-line or Makefile?  If command-line, please verify which compiler (gcc)?  If Makefile, please edit the question and include your current Makefile attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -static your_program.c  -L ./LIB -lbson -o your_program
```

where `libbson` is stored inside `./LIB`.

Comment: I wouldn't use `-static` here, just link against a libbson.a though